# SQLAlchemy and PyMySQL SSL Connection Issue with Hosting Service

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, render.com

I’m working on a Flask application that uses SQLAlchemy and PyMySQL to connect to a MySQL database hosted on Render.com. I’m facing SSL connection issues, and I’m not sure how to configure the SSL parameters correctly.

Here's a snippet:

```
load_dotenv()
db_connect_string = os.getenv('DB_STR')

# Creating the engine.
engine = create_engine(db_connect_string, connect_args={"ssl_ca": "/etc/ssl/cert.pem"})
```

I’ve tried different variations of the ssl_ca parameter, but I keep encountering SSL-related errors, such as “server does not allow insecure connections” or “FileNotFoundError” for the certificate file.

Render.com provides SSL certificates, but I’m unsure about how to correctly configure the SSL parameters in SQLAlchemy and PyMySQL for this hosting environment. The service documentation mentions that SSL is handled automatically.

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Render will handle SSL certificates automatically for you on *managed* services, like their managed postgres instances or SSL for public facing servers.

I'm not sure how you're deploying mysql into your workspace, but if you're using the render [mysql example](https://github.com/render-examples/mysql), you wont get SSL out of the box- you'll need to set that up yourself.

In the example case, you'll need to generate your own SSL certs, add them to your mount volume, and configure mysql to point to them. ([some docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-encrypted-connections.html#using-encrypted-connections-server-side-startup-configuration))

If you've done that setup already and the problem is that your DB connection can't find the cert in your mount volume or in your local filesystem (maybe you committed the cert into your repo), you can always upgrade your plan to starter and SSH to your service to navigate around the filesystem to find the cert and get the correct path, or have the startup log some paths for you so you can figure out the correct path and then put that in your code.